# Normal map is dark blue?

Tags: normals, baking

My normal map turned suddenly into dark blue, does abyone know how to turn into into light blue? High Poly Model, Low poly Model and Cage -> baked got light blue, added something to my highpoly, baked again -> now dark blue....

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use Non-color Color Space, make sure you don't apply the normal map to the mesh from which you bake the normal map.

Answer (score -1):

disconnect your nodes on the normal map... thats what worked for me